# How to disable localhost/dashboard directory listing in xampp

Tags: xampp

Whenever I open localhost it redirects to this directory listing. Previously it used to show the index.html page "Welcome to XAMPP" now it shows directory listing. How do I revert it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason if xampp stops recognizing the dashboard `index.html` file simply edit `xampp/htdocs/index.php` file and edit the following line and add `/index.html` at the end of the line.

```php
header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/index.html');
```

This will make sure that the index.html is loaded rather than displaying the Directory listing.